# bind image dynamically Angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have `object array` which I need to add image icon dynamically based on type of credit card,

**ts file**

```
  icon: any;

  savedCreditCard = 
  [
  {
    cardExpiryDateFormat: "05/xx",
    cardNumberLast: "00xx",
    cardId: "xxx",
    cardType: "Mastercard",
    cardExpiryDate: "xx05",
    paymentChannelId: 9,
    cardNumberMasked: "512345XXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  {
    cardExpiryDateFormat: "11/xx",
    cardNumberLast: "58xx",
    cardId: "xxx",
    cardType: "Amex",
    cardExpiryDate: "xx11",
    paymentChannelId: 16,
    cardNumberMasked: "379185XXXXXXXXX"
  }
]

  ngOnInit() {
        this.savedCreditCard.forEach((x => {
      if (x.cardType === 'Mastercard') {
        this.icon = '../../assets/svg/logo-mastercard.svg';
      } else if (x.cardType === 'Amex') {
        this.icon = '../../assets/svg/icon-amex.svg';
      }
    })
    );
  }
```

and on HTML template, I try to binding image dynamically based on type of credit card, this is what I had tried,

**html file**

```
    <div class="flex-float">
      <div class="float-end">
        <img class="select--icon" [src]="icon" />
        <p class="selected--desc is-hidden-mobile-xs">
          {{ selectedCard.cardType }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the problem is I only got same icon eventhough is mastercard or amex, I want to reproduce on stackblitz, but it not supported static image,  anyone know how to solve this or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one `icon` variable and it is being reassigned a new icon path on each `forEach()` iteration. And this one `icon` is used for all cards, therefore only one image is being displayed.

**Approach 1:**

You could have an object of icons like

```
var icons = {
 'Mastercard': '../../assets/svg/logo-mastercard.svg',
 'Amex': '../../assets/svg/icon-amex.svg'
};
```

And in HTML, just use the appropriate icon based on card type.

```
<div class="flex-float">
  <div class="float-end">
    <img class="select--icon" [src]="icons[selectedCard.cardType]" />
      <p class="selected--desc is-hidden-mobile-xs">
        {{ selectedCard.cardType }}
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

No need to make any changes to `saveCreditCard` array in `ngOnInit()`.

**Approach 2:**

If you want to store icon on each object in `saveCreditCard`, then [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used.

In `ngOnInit()`, assign icon to each credit card.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.savedCreditCard = this.savedCreditCard.map(card => {
    let icon;
    if (card.cardType === 'Mastercard') {
      icon = '../../assets/svg/logo-mastercard.svg';
    } else if (card.cardType === 'Amex') {
      icon = '../../assets/svg/icon-amex.svg';
    }

    return {...card, "icon": icon};
  }); 
}
```

Then in HTML, use the card's `icon` property.

```
<div class="flex-float">
  <div class="float-end">
    <img class="select--icon" [src]="selectedCard.icon" />
      <p class="selected--desc is-hidden-mobile-xs">
        {{ selectedCard.cardType }}
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more about approach 2, yeah and it is work

Comment: Sure @jajanato. We are using `map()` method to add `icon` property to each object in `savedCreditCard` array. Check out MDN documentation on [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to see how it works. Then we are using this image path as icon in HTML when displaying all the cards. I hope this helped. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `return {...card, "icon": icon};`  this code make me confuse, why we had ... and it can be simpler like this `return {..card, icon};`